# Despaginar un array paginado Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, paginación, querybuilder

Tengo una consulta que me devuelve un conjunto de registros, esta consulta tiene un paginate por lo que el array viene paginado...

El problema es que tengo un boton llamado "Select All" que deberia seleccionarme todos los registros de ese array y extraerme el user_id de cada registro, por lo que debo ciclarlo con un foreach, pero el problema es que al estar paginado solo me devuelve los registros de la primera pagina...

¿Como podria despaginar esto para recorrerlo como un array normal?

```
$data = DB::table('mensajeros')
            ->join('personas','mensajeros.persona_id','=','personas.id')
            ->join('users','personas.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->select('users.id as id','personas.nombres','personas.ap_paterno','personas.ap_materno','personas.ci','users.estado')
            ->where('users.estado','=',$this->status)
            ->paginate(10);

$otherData = [];
foreach($data as $user){
array_push($otherData, $user->id);
}
```

Algo asi...

Comment: Y no puede hacer una segunda consulta exacta a la anterior sin el `paginate` y seleccionando solo el user.id?

Comment: Claro que puedo pero hay un problema... veras, tengo un switch con 6 opciones distintas, dependiendo el tipo de usuario se mostrará en la vista una cosa u otra.
Me parece algo poco practico tener 12 consultas para algo asi... ademas de que a la larga, posiblemente necesite repetir este procedimiento y odiaria tener que realizar una consulta entera otra vez teniendolo ya paginado. Otra opcion tambien podria ser hacer la consulta DESPAGINADA, guardarlo en una variable y luego paginarla, pero no se como hacer ninguno de los dos casos

Comment: Pero esto ya parece tema es para otra pregunta, en la pregunta actual no incluyes nada de esto de lo que hablas y así es complicado ayudarte. Lo que si estoy seguro es que si la páginas pues obviamente solo te va a devolver la info de una única página, pero hablas de tener todos los registros, entonces esa consulta no debe ser paginada. Lo que tu llamas "despaginar" se podría traducir como "no paginar"

Comment: Bien. lo que busco es, teniendo un array paginado poder meterlo dentro de un foreach para extraer el user_id de cada registro de ese array sin importar la paginacion.  El problema es que tu crees que yo necesito solo uno, pero no es asi, necesito el array paginado y el no_paginado, pero no quiero tener que hacer dos consultas independientes para cada caso.

Comment: ahh... entonces creo que lo que neceitas es `foreach($data->items() as $user){ ... }`